# Plupload: How to upload directly from a camera (on mobile devices)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, file-upload, plupload

I'm using [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) to let users upload images to my WordPress website.

When a user clicks on 'Select files' and chooses an image from their mobile phone's gallery, the image's filename appears on screen. The user is then free to click on 'Upload files' to start the upload.

**My problem**

When a user clicks on 'Select files' and takes a photo with their camera phone, the image's filename doesn't appear on screen. In this case, when the user now tries clicking on 'Upload files', nothing happens. How can I resolve this?

**Notes**

The problem doesn't happen at all when I use my tablet or desktop.

**Update**

My testing was done using two mobile devices:

1. Chrome on a Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini running Android 4.2.2
2. Chrome on a Samsung Galaxy Ace II running Android 4.1.2

Here's a demo of the code I'm using: http://jsfiddle.net/djydce90/

**My script**

```
var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
  runtimes : 'html5,flash,silverlight,html4',
  browse_button : 'pickfiles',
  container: document.getElementById( 'container' ),
  url : "/examples/upload",
  filters : {
    max_file_size : '10mb',
    mime_types: [
      {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png"},
      {title : "Zip files", extensions : "zip"}
    ]
  },
  flash_swf_url : '/plupload/js/Moxie.swf',
  silverlight_xap_url : '/plupload/js/Moxie.xap',
  init: {
    PostInit: function() {
      document.getElementById('filelist').innerHTML = '';

      document.getElementById('uploadfiles').onclick = function() {
        uploader.start();
        return false;
      };
    },
    FilesAdded: function(up, files) {
      plupload.each(files, function(file) {
        document.getElementById('filelist').innerHTML += '<div id="' + file.id + '">' + file.name + ' (' + plupload.formatSize(file.size) + ') <b></b></div>';
      });
    },
    UploadProgress: function(up, file) {
      document.getElementById(file.id).getElementsByTagName('b')[0].innerHTML = '<span>' + file.percent + "%</span>";
    },
    Error: function(up, err) {
      document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "\nError #" + err.code + ": " + err.message;
    }
  }
});

uploader.init();
```

**My HTML**

```
<script src="https://rawgit.com/moxiecode/plupload/master/js/plupload.full.min.js"></script>
<div id="filelist">Your browser doesn't have Flash, Silverlight or HTML5 support.</div>
<br />
<div id="container">
  <a id="pickfiles" href="javascript:;">[Select files]</a>
  <a id="uploadfiles" href="javascript:;">[Upload files]</a>
</div>
```

**Ref:** http://www.plupload.com/examples/core

Comment: I am also having a similar issue with the plupload example on my android (HTC one : custom rom) .... It may have to do with plupload it's self : or that particular implementation.      (If you would like I can suggest a different solution if your able to change dependencies)

Comment: @Burdock Can I ask which version of Android your HTC is running? And please do suggest a different solution if you have one :)

Comment: @henrtywright Android 4.2.2 : HTC sense 5.0 : HTC SDK api level 5.34: Trickdroid 7.5.something  ..... and Chrome

Comment: Thanks @Burdock. Thus far, I've done a total of 4 Android tests and 1 iOS test. The problem seems to happen only on Android handsets running a version of Android under 4.4.2.

Comment: I personally don't use any library to handle uploading files. Its worth learning how to do your self if you have the time. Otherwise jQuery-File-Upload is IMO the easiest library to implement quickly : https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Comment: If you want a small tutorial on how to do this with raw Ajax/jQuery/javascript/http/whatever I can post it as an answer :P

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll check it out. I'm only using Plupload because it's the library used by WordPress core, all I really need to do is enqueue the script and then set up some basic config. Call me lazy but it seems to get the job done (aside from this issue) :P

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from method of capturing images.Android gives you a bitmap object when you take a pic,so you need to upload that bitmap instead of a file.When  you select a file from your memory it sends you that path but in capturing you give that photo data in details . so you need to upload that photo data instead of uploading a file.I don't know exactly can pluplaoad handle this or no but you can go through this link to get a sight of it.

- [Showing Plupload Image Previews Using Base64-Encoded Data Urls](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2563-showing-plupload-image-previews-using-base64-encoded-data-urls.htm)